# Carrusel en Angular

Tags: bootstrap, angular-cli

Buenas noches fijense que quiero hacer un carrusel usando angular-cli y bootstrap tengo el código y las imagenes este es el código

```html
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="./../../assets/imagenes/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="1">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="./../../assets/imagenes/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="2">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="./../../assets/imagenes/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="3">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

El problema es que cuando quiero cambiar de imagen no pasa nada. Soy bastante nuevo en este tipo de programación web, ayudenme por favor.

Comment: Hola Otoniel, te invito a que visites [¿Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). Con el código que nos proporcionas no podemos ejecutar con facilidad el error que tienes.